# How to run PowerShell command from SharePoint Script Editor?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, powershell, classic-experience, script-webpart

I want to run PowerShell command (any command) from SharePoint Script Editor.

Please let me know how can I achieve it?

I use the below script to lunch notepad, just to test it, and even it doesn't work:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function LaunchApp() {
   var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
   shell.run("notepad.exe", 1, True);
};

</script>
<button type="button" id="btn" onclick=LaunchApp()>Run App</button>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible due to crossing the security boundary of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Trevor's point of view. By design, the Script Editor Web Part does not support running any powershell commands.